# SendGrid Domain Authentication Heroku

Tags: authentication, heroku, sendgrid, responsive-emails

I'm using heroku and need to authenticate domain for sendgrid. But i can't do so since heroku already have subdomain url like http://xyz.herokuapp.com .
can anyone suggest a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Sendgrid no longer cares about developers, and is choosing to limit their services to projects that have already purchased a domain. Several updates have been made lately by Sendgrid which no longer makes it a simple 'out of the box' solution for Heroku, which was the entire appeal of Sendgrid (in my opinion.)

[image: hat with sendgrid support]

Sendgrid used to be so simple and easy to integrate, but it now requires a lot of setup, just to test some simple emails. I would suggest looking into other emailing services if you are just learning or want to send from a herokuapp without a whitelabeled domain.